# On profile page, bounties show as open no matter what

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, profile-page

When on the `Bounties` tab on a user's profile page, I noticed that no matter whether a bounty had been awarded already or not, it shows as an "open bounty".

[image: Old bounties on user profile pages]

Here is the page I was using in the screenshot: [Tom Brossman](https://askubuntu.com/users/12864/tom-brossman?tab=bounties)

As you can see, that bounty has already been awarded:

[image: Bounty already awarded]

Here is the question I was using in the screenshot: [Apply compressor effect to new podcasts automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/q/90568/72212)

There was no "Open Bounty" banner on the page in sight.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the tooltip only. I suspect it's just a template taken from the front page. The profile page itself correctly only lists these questions in the "offered" tab but not the "active" tab.

Comment: Yep, it would seem that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an oversight when some code was re-used, they'll display "had a bounty" rather than "has an open bounty" where it applies after the next build.